# Find text hidden in jQuery slideToggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm not used to JQuery and I'm trying to allow my web browser to search (CTRL+F) text in div that are hidden by a onClick="slideToggle()", is there a way to do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're hiding the text. If you're making the display = "none" or visibility hidden I don't believe you'll be able to do it.
However, if you were to move the div off the page, hide another div on top of it, or make the text the same color as the background it would still be searchable by CTRL-F. The text would still not be visible but the find function would still see it.

To clarify, you could have a div off screen and JQuery that checks your position on the page, moving the div over to a visible position whenever you are scrolled down that far. Then when you CTRL-F for that string it would move you down trigger the jquery and push the DIV into a visible position.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you. I thought it was possible to "CTRL-F" a string and the div would have uncollapsed itself if the string was in it.

Comment: I updated my solution with something that might work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was not what I expected from jQuery but your solution is good.